# WSO2 ESB- PayloadFactory for different operations

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a backend service with multiple operations. (for example,echoInt and echoString). I want to replace input value for both of them with predefined variables(in the inSequence)  with **PayloadFactory** mediator. 
How can i define payloadfactory for different operations? 
when i define two payloadfactory mediator for each of them, only the last mediator works for it's operation. when i call other opertaion, this error occures:

```
wso2 namespace mismatch
```

operation1:

```
<p:echoString xmlns:p="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
  <in>$1</in>
</p:echoString>
```

operation2:

```
<p:echoInt xmlns:p="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">      
   <in>$1</in>
</p:echoInt>
```

My inSequense:

```
   <inSequence>
     <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
           <p:echoString xmlns:p="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
              <in xmlns="">teststr</in>
           </p:echoString>
        </format>
        <args/>
     </payloadFactory>
     <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
           <p:echoInt xmlns:p="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
              <in xmlns="">1111</in>
           </p:echoInt>
        </format>
        <args/>
     </payloadFactory>
  </inSequence>
```

with above inSequense, output result for both operations is '1111':

```
 <ns:echoStringResponse xmlns:ns="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
     <return>1111</return>
 </ns:echoStringResponse>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: How exactly are you defining the two Payload Factories? In a Switch mediator?

Comment: add your full inSequence to the question

Comment: I don't have switch mediator. how can i use switch mediator with payloadfactory? I added my full inSequense to the question. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second Payload factory replaces the first. 
If you want to use each of them in a different case, you should define them in a Switch mediator.

You can use a property to get the input that defines which case you should use, then use regex to match the property value. Or you could skip the property and enter the expression in the Switch source.

At the end it would look similar to:

```
<inSequence>
    <property expression="/default/expression" name="input_string" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <switch source="get-property('input_string')">
        <case regex="[\w\s]+">
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <p:echoString xmlns:p="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
                        <in xmlns="">teststr</in>
                    </p:echoString>
                </format>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
        </case>
        <default>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <p:echoInt xmlns:p="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
                        <in xmlns="">1111</in>
                    </p:echoInt>
                </format>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
        </default>
    </switch>
    <respond/>
</inSequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want call two operations in same time, you should use the clone or iterate Mediator, and use the aggregate Mediator in the outsequence.

The reason you use the two payloadFactory, only last one works, is that one request only have one message context, this mean, you only can send one soap message to back end in same time. This mean the last payloadFactory will override the first one.

Clone or iterate Mediator will clone or split one message context to multiple message context, then you can send multiple soap message to back end services. Because of you got multiple message context, then you should use the aggregate Mediator to aggregate these multiple responses into one message context after back end services return the result.